# How do I get the Logitech wingman formula force to work in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-gamepad

How can I make the Logitech Wingman Formula Force steering wheel work in Vista and 64 bit Windows 7?

Answer (score 7):

Download 64-bit drivers for the Saitek R440 from here

```
ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/full/Saitek_R440_Force_Wheel_SD6_64.exe
```

If this link stops working, you can visit the Saitek page here

```
http://www.saitek.com/uk/down/drivers.php
```

Extract the `Saitek_R440_Force_Wheel_SD6_64.exe` file somewhere (You might need Winrar to extract the `*.exe`).

Now, you need to find the hardware id for your wheel. Plug everything in, and go to your device manager. You'll see Wingman or something with a yellow ! next to it. Right click it > properties > details tab > select hardware id from the drop down menu.

It will look like this..

```
USB\VID_046D&PID_C291&REV_0100
```

Now, go to the folder where you extracted the Saitek drivers, in the `FF04` folder, open the file `SaiFF04.inf`

Look for `[SAITEK_MODELS.NTamd64]` below that there are 2 lines. Paste your hardware id onto the second line after the `SAI_USB_Inst,`. It will look like this:

```
%USB_NAME%= SAI_USB_Inst, USB\VID_046D&PID_C291&REV_0100
```

All you need to do now, is find your wheel in the device manager, select "driver update" and point your browser to the folder with the saitek drivers in. The edited .inf file will make windows assume this is the correct driver and install it.

I tested and calibrated this. It works really well

Comment: That's great, thanks @user. I've also taken the liberty of tweaking the formatting on this post so it's a bit more pleasant to look at. Finally, in ~two days you'll be able to tick this answer as the accepted answer - unfortunately there's a 48hr time restriction for accepting your own answers.

Comment: The feedback doesn't work!
Suggestions?
(I have tried with F12010)

tks

Comment: not sure if it works (yet) but some instructions claim to work: http://forums.logitech.com/t5/PC-Gaming/Logitech-Wingman-Formula-Force-red-wheel-Driver-support-in-Vista/td-p/335686/page/2

Comment: that actually seems to work. replaced all occurences in the .inf file directly prior to installing them to avoid having to rename folders in regedit though.

Comment: Pre-modified drivers are now available here: http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Logitech-G-Controllers/Wingman-Formula-Force-and-Windows-7-x64/m-p/974933#M13561 .. Can test basic operation by going to Devices and Printers, right click on wheel, select Game Controller Settings, select Properties.

Comment: I can confirm this driver works for Windows 7 64bit, and Windows 8(.1) 64bit, but not Windows 10 64bit, the driver works but games which use the steering wheel crash! Also the thread for the pre-modified drivers is gone, can someone please re-upload them somewhere?

Comment: @Alex - Here's the link to the archived post and pre-modded driver: http://web.archive.org/web/20160105064639/http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Logitech-G-Controllers/Wingman-Formula-Force-and-Windows-7-x64/m-p/974933?nobounce --- It is a challenge to install it on modern machines and Win10 due to tighter security with modded drivers. Search "bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON" for help. I had to first turn off Secure Boot in my BIOS before I could run BCDEDIT as admin, reboot again, then install modded driver, then reverse those changes. But... RBR 2016 runs great with this wheel now on Win10-64.

Comment: @juanitogan Thank you so much! I will try this!